# Making text files into arrays

Tags: c#

So here is the overall gist of my project:
I have three files: file1, file2 and file3. Inside these files are a bunch of emails. file1 is supposed to have all emails in it, where file2 has one set and file3 has another set. I need to write a program that will read these files, see which emails are missing out of these 3 emails and then write to a new file called master file and the output of the master file has to tell me which emails are missing out of each file.

For example, lets say that Anna is in file2, but Anna is not found in file1. The output of the master file should tell me that I need to add Anna to file1 (I know Anna is not an email but this is just an example.)

Below I have the code that I have been working on, and I have a code for finding and or writing the text files. My question is how do I take these files and put them into an array so I can sort them and get the output that I want. Or how if that is not how you go about this, what is the way I have to go about this.

```
    class Program
    {
const string file1 = "file1.txt";
const string file2 = "file2.txt";
const string file3 = "file3.txt";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
            try
    {
     var count = File.ReadLines(file1).Count();
        //This code simply checks if the full_pack file exists and if it does, it will give how many lines are in the file
        if (!File.Exists(file1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
        }

        else
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file1));
            Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());

        }

        //this code is similar to the one above, however it is for den1
        if (!File.Exists(file2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file2));
            Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());
        }

        //this code is similar to the one above, however it is for den2
        if (!File.Exists(file3))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file3);
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file3));
            Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());
        }

        //This code is to create a new file called masterfile
        string masterFile = @"C:\Users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BoyscoutProject2\BoyscoutProject2\Data\masterFile.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(masterFile))
        {
            File.Create(masterFile);
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(masterFile);
            tw.WriteLine("Here is the list of missing emails");
            tw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(masterFile))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(masterFile);
            tw.WriteLine("Here is the list of missing emails");
            tw.Close();
        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: yea, tagging it with c# usually gives us this information too.

Comment: on topic: you already have the line `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);` which gets all the emails into an array, so what is the problem?

Comment: It gets it into array yes, I need to know though how to get all the information from all three of those files, see which emails are missing from those files, and then have the output of master file read what emails I need to add from which file to file1.

Comment: Thank you everyone who has helped in this long coding process. I appreciate all of the hard work everyone has put in to make this code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HadiRj has a good point using a `HashSet`, but the logic was wrong. you need to remove from files 2 and 3 all the records that are currently in file one, so records that will remain in files 2 and 3 are those there werent in file1 in the first place:

```
string[] file1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt");
string[] file2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file2.txt");
string[] file3 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file3.txt");

HashSet<string> missingFromTwo = new HashSet<string>(file2);
HashSet<string> missingFromThree = new HashSet<string>(file3);

//this line will remove all etries in file1 from file2,
//hence file2 will remain with entries that do not exist
//in file one.
missingFromTwo.ExceptWith(file1);

//this line will do the same with file3.
missingFromThree.ExceptWith(file1);

StringBuilder FinalResult = new StringBuilder();
FinalResult.AppendLine("emails from file 2 that need to be added to file1:");
FinalResult.Append(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, missingFromTwo.ToArray()));


FinalResult.AppendLine("emails from file 3 that need to be added to file1:");
FinalResult.Append(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, missingFromThree.ToArray()));

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Master.txt", FinalResult.ToString());
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the last line of code. No matter what I do, it will give me an overloaded error

Comment: @PatrickOvermyer the last line just outputs it all into a file. i wrote that from memory, just google how to output string builder to a file.

Comment: this is great. I believe that this is finally the code that I have been looking for. Thank you so much for all of your help I very much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, I wrote this code here without testing. Hope it will give you some idea.

```
string[] file1Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt");
string[] file2Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file2.txt");
string[] file3Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file3.txt");
var file2Missings = file2Content.Except(file1Content);
var file3Missings = file3Content.Except(file1Content);
string[] MasterFileContent = file2Missings.Concat(file3Missings).Distinct().ToArray();

foreach(string s in MasterFileContent.Distinct().ToArray())
      Console.WriteLine(s + " must be placed in file 1");
```

**UPDATE**

You can see it running here: http://goo.gl/3fP56T

Comment: Could you explain what your purpose of MasterFilePath is?

Comment: @PatrickOvermyer MasterFilePath is the path of the master file. Replace it with `C:\Users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BoyscoutProject2\BoyscoutProject2\Data\masterFile.txt` path that you provided in question.

Comment: The code is just giving me all the emails that I already have. I need it to tell me what emails aren't in what file. Like I said in the question: if Anna is in file2 but not in file1, the output has to say "Anna needs to be placed in file1"

Comment: @PatrickOvermyer I updated my code. I think this is what you wanted. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code:
**Edited**

```
        //Check if files are available
        var file1 = File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt");
        var file2 = File.ReadAllLines("file2.txt");
        var file3 = File.ReadAllLines("file3.txt");
        var result = "result.txt";
        var ThreeAndTwo = file3.Concat(file2);
        foreach (var email in ThreeAndTwo)
        {
            if (!file1.Contains(email))
                File.AppendAllText(result, email + " needs to be placed in file1" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

**Edit 2** demonstrating results

content of file1.txt

> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3
>
> test4
>
> test5

content of file2.txt

> test2
>
> test22
>
> test22

content of file3.txt

> test3
>
> test33
>
> test333

content of result.txt

> test22 needs to be placed in file1
>
> test222 needs to be placed in file1
>
> test33 needs to be placed in file1
>
> test333 needs to be placed in file1

Comment: Does that say though that this email is missing from file1

Comment: this solution does the exact opposite. it returns only the emails that exist in all 3 files, and not the missing ones.

Comment: @HadiRj your code actually isn't doing anything :( when you runtime it the code runs but the text is not going into the file

Comment: @PatrickOvermyer I added results that I get using my code, you are probably checking a wrong file!